# Annoying! CloudWatch Dashboards go to home page after every few minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, assume-role

We've built dashboards for service monitoring using **AWS CloudWatch** and **Logs Insights**. Everything looks great from reporting perspective. However, something very annoying is happening on the screen where we want to set it up to constantly display the service performance. Our setup is

1. We use **AWS STS/Assume Role** from Identities account to login to our Development and Production accounts
2. CloudWatch Dashboards are on Production accounts

We've below problems which we are looking at solving immediately:

1. The **STS token expires** every **12 hours (max)**. Is there anyway we can keep the sessions running for more than 12 hours? We don't want to be logging onto every service monitoring machine every morning.
2. Every few minutes CloudWatch exits from Display Dashboard and lands on CloudWatch home page on the monitoring screen
3. How to get rid of `Alarms by Service` and `Recent Alarms` widgets on CloudWatch home page?

I referred to this thread on [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=226352), but it has no posts or resolutions from many months :-(

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really much you can do here until AWS decides to change how that works. I'm with you, it's really annoying, and makes it far less valuable. I did learn one trick on this, however. When you do end up back on the home page you can use your browsers back button and you'll most often be back to where you were. That at least saves you from having to reenter things.